# How to define the schema property in tomcat connection

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, tomcat, hikaricp

I would like to change the hikari db pool to tomcat pool. In my property file i have a hikari.schema value defined. How do i define this config value for tomcat connetion pool? It all worked before.

The property was defined like this:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: my-schema
```

I got the folling exception and i think it's because the schema is missing some where

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1554) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.13.Final.jar:5.3.13.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:2.1.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Relation Supplier existiert nicht
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
```

Comment: can you show how did you specified that property ? in old and current code ? probably it will help you can add exception with stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike **HikariCP** and **DBCP2**, **Tomcat JDBC** does not have a *"default schema"* property (cf. [available properties](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)).

Fortunately, since you are using PostgreSQL, you can set the default schema as *connection property* by:

- either adding it to the URL: `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?currentSchema=my-schema`
- or by adding `currentSchema=my-schema` in the `connectionProperties` property of the datasource, which in Spring YAML should look like:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    tomcat:
      connection-properties: "currentSchema=my-schema"
```

See also: [PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Parameters](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

Comment: Thanks, connection-properties has worked for me