# Running tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I am trying to setup an application in Eclipse with a local tomcat server. It is getting started but with errors. The error is related to the Table not present in Database.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table" does not exist
```

However, if I give the schema name along with the table in the query, it runs fine. I cannot add schema names to the queries in the entire application. This application runs entirely fine in the server. can someone suggest a way to rectify this.

EDIT: I use context.xml to connect to Database.

```
   <Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    maxTotal="30"
    maxIdle="3" maxWaitMillis="100000"
    password="<Password>" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<DB_NAME>"
    username="postgres"
    removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
    removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="20"
    logAbandoned="true"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    validationQuery="select 1"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
    numTestsPerEvictionRun="10"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="false"/>
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with Eclipse, please describe in your question how do you connect to your database? If you use JNDI add the Tomcat resource configuration.

Comment: I edited my question with the context.xml for the database

Answer (score 0):

Since [version 2.5.0](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/changes-report.html#a2.5.0) (released in July 2018), DBCP 2 added a `defaultSchema` property to its datasource. Tomcat picked it up in [version 9.0.11](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.11_(markt))  and [version 8.5.33](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#8.5.33_(markt)).

Therefore if you run an up-to-date version of Tomcat, you can use:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<DB_NAME>"
          defaultSchema="<your_schema>"
          ...
```

For a similar solution using Tomcat JDBC Pool, see [How to define the schema property in tomcat connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66785651/11748454).

**Edit:** You can also append multiple schemas to the URL:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<DB_NAME>?options=-c%20searchpath=schema1,schema2,schema3,schema4,...,public,pgcatalog"
          ...
```

Comment: But I have more than 15 schemas in my Database. So I cannot default it to one particular schema.

Comment: You can add all schemas to the connection URL: `?options=-c%20searchpath=schema1,schema2,schema3,schema4,...,public,pgcatalog`. However your application should probably call `Connection#setSchema` whenever it borrows a connection from the pool.

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz Your comment answered my question. Can you please post it as an anwer?